# Insert Data from one table to another in the Same Database due to import wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-import-wizard

firstly i am new to Programming and SQL (7 Months) and this is the first time i have done this. i am self taught for the most part.

here it goes,

I have an Excel spreadsheet with all the data in it, all the column names correspond with the 
names in the database. i used the wizard and successfully managed to import the data.
HOWEVER rather than insert the data into the target tables as i wanted the stupid thing (which doesn't let you amend the destination btw) created new tables (exactly the same as the tables i had created except with a $ at the end) and inserted everything there!

I've tried a few things and this is the best and as close as I can get so my question is

How the hell do I now transfer ALL the records from the created tables into where I need them?

we are talking about 4 tables (in a 7 table DB) and hundreds of inserts in two of the tables and over 2,000 in the other two.

the proper tables are

```
dbo.Crystal
dbo.Essential
dbo.MineOp
dbo.Origin
```

the falsely created tables are 
    dbo.Crystal$
    dbo.Essential$
    dbo.MineOp$
    dbo.Origin$

all the columns and values etc are the same they are in fact identical copies of each other
but i need the $ ones into the original ones (that have keys and constraints) and then ill delete the false tables.

Can I do these in Bulk?? if so someone PLEASE give me the EXACT Script syntax i need to do this, as i have no idea. i know my basic commands and insert statements, don't know what let alone how a JOIN or MERGE/R is? let alone how to do it

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 (Express)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [JDatabase].[dbo].[MineOp] (Name)
SELECT Name
FROM [JDatabase].[dbo].[MineOp$];
```

and the same for the other tables just with the other table details!
thanks for the negative vote!